# Most efficient structure of an iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Im developing an iOS application and I'm stuck on how to design the structure of it. Here is what I have so far:
The app is called "Time Clock" and it allows users to clock in and out. The app will generate time stamps when a user clocks in or out respectively. As far as data goes, I already have a large MySQL database that is already being used for a similar Windows desktop application. (I'm trying to cater to my company's iPhone users)

My question is, what should I do about the data structures in this app? Can Core Data retrieve the MySQL data (through a web service) and manage it? Should I use data controller classes to manage the data? I don't know the best way to handle the data.

Here are the data fields that need to be managed:

- Store
- Name
- PIN
- Timestamp In
- Timestamp Out

All in all, what is the most efficient way to manage the data in an app such as this? If you could point me in the right direction i would be very thankful! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Core data wont be able to retrieve anything from a webservice,  you need to make a data access layer that will return that data to you via [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and the like, there is a lot of information out there on how to do this...  I would recommend modeling some classes that basically your data layer will fill for the rest of your application to work with. Also if your data is shared across many views i would suggest making some singleton class that will keep the data already retrieved, this way you can access it across different UIViewControllers in your application. Way I would structure this is

DataAccessLayer (layer that consumes your webservices, and fills the info into classes (your model)) -> Some Singleton class that keeps your objects from your webservices -> UIViewControllers (these will talk to your data access layer/ Singleton class for the data it needs which in turn uses it to fill your views ->VIEWS - > if changes occur to your model relay that to your webservices via the data access layer

... As far as core data, you can use that if you want to persist the data in your application, but its not necesary otherwise, i should point out that core data is not the only way to persist data in your application... This answer is a bit general but hope it can point you to the right direction..

Daniel

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Exactly what I needed to hear.

Comment: Just as another point, if you want to understand about how to use the network efficiently and effectively take a look at the articles here, they explain how cellular networks differ from fixed and how to deal with that http://developer.att.com/developer/forward.jsp?passedItemId=7200042