# Passing data to the view controller that UINavigationController points to

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

So heres my question. I am a silent stackoverflow skimmer and Im using xcode 4.5 storyboards for an application which starts with a view controller which asks for the username and password. My application checks data via a backend server and then if the login is correct it performs a segue which points to the uinavigationcontroller which forwards the screen to the main menu.... The uinavigationcontroller hasnt been tampered with and pushes the mainmenu automatically.

```
Login_screen -> UINavigationController -> Main_Menu
```

My question is how do i pass the `NSString` username from the login screen to the main menu screen.

I understand how to pass data from one screen to the next when the segue is pointing directly to it via the `prepareforsegue` method as well as `performsegue`. But in this case the `login_screen` segue points to the `uinaviationcontroller` which points to the `main_menu controller`

My assumption is that i will need to make a custom class which inherits `UINavigationController` and implement certain methods but since `uinavigationcontroller` isnt seen i dont think `viewdidload` or `viewwillappear` are the right methods.

Any help will be appreciated

I am a new user so i am not allowed to post images but i will fix that as soon as possible

Comment: If you are sharing your data across viewControllers i would suggest having some central point of access for your webservice data, check my answer for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146575/most-efficient-structure-of-an-ios-app/13146671#13146671

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the topViewController property of the UINavigationController.

Cast the UINavigationController.topViewController object to Main_MenuViewController and set the data normally.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

in whatever case you need some container to persist the current selected/active object. I f for whatever reason you can't extend the UINavigationController (I'd wonder why), you can always have some property in AppDelegate you can assign and in your final Main_Menu controller read this property.

Smth like this:

```
AppDelegate* app = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSObject* myThing = app.myObj
if(!myThing) {
    app.myObj = ...
}
```